# Does FireMonkey have anything similar to GetSystemMetrics?

Tags: delphi, firemonkey

I'm rewriting an old application using Delphi 2010 and I'd like to put placeholders in my code for when I port it over to XE2. Just curious if FireMonkey has an equivilent to  GetSystemMetrics. I'm specifically interested in:

- GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXSCREEN)
- GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYSCREEN)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you just need the main monitor size, and not the desktop size (*n* monitors sum), you can use this:

```
uses ..., FMX.Platform;


var
  p: TPointF;
begin
  p := Platform.GetScreenSize;
  ShowMessage(Format('X: %f' + LineFeed + 'Y: %f', [p.X, p.Y]));
```

[image: Windows] [image: OS X]

Comment: Just gave you a shoutout on my blog... http://capecodgunny.blogspot.com/2012/05/keeping-screen-resolution-in-mind.html

Answer (score 1):

In fact `SM_CXSCREEN` and `SM_CYSCREEN` should probably not be used at all. That just tells you the dimensions of the primary monitor. In these days of multiple monitors, that's not terribly useful. In VCL code you should be using `Screen.Monitors[]` and related properties to obtain information about your monitors.

As for FMX, there is no multi-monitor support and no platform independent way to find out screen size metrics. In your shoes I would simply use `Screen.Monitors[]` and deal with the FMX port when you get to it. You are going to have to re-write all your GUI code anyway when you port to FMX and this particular issue is the least of your worries.

Finally, when you say

> I'd like to put placeholders in my code for when I port it over to XE2

I trust you are aware that porting to FMX is not compulsory. The VCL is still supported and available in XE2 and I can't see it being removed for a long time to come. You can port to XE2 without having anything to do with FMX.

Comment: I'm working on creating an IniFile initialization routine. The only reason I wanted SM_CXSCREEN and SM_CYSCREEN was set the values for the IniFile if it hasn't been created yet. I could pick arbitrary values but I wanted to set the main screen at 80% of the primary monitor.

Comment: OK, in that case, `SM_CXSCREEN` is plausible. As an aside, why bother initialising an ini file of preferences. If the ini file is not present, then create default values. And then save the preferences when the app closes. That way you don't have to write special code to initialise it, and it can be robust to deletion. But that's off topic.

Comment: @CapeCodGunny: Agree with David's approach to the ini file. Just make sure that all reads of values out of the ini file use a proper default value, preferably a constant that comes from some mydefaultconsts.pas unit. That way you are safe for all values, even if someone creates the ini file manually and not all values have been set.

Comment: @Marjan - Agreed, we are on the same page. I'm using a unit called IniFileStuff.pas that has the deafults built right into it. Initally I was setting screen defaults to 80% of SM_CXSCREEN and SM_CYSCREEN but I like 85% better.